# How to move ImageView with custom speed?

Tags: android, animation

I would like to create simple moving object when Activity starts, but I can't find solution for that.

Let's say I have this ImageView:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image"/>
```

And here is my testing Activity:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        View view = super.onCreateView(name, context, attrs);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use an animation:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);

    TranslateAnimation ta = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,300,200);
    ta.setDuration(5000);
    img.startAnimation(ta);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html